# How to convert Geostatistical analyst (GA) file to Raster FAST?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, geostatistical-analyst

I have been trying to convert a number of Geostatistical analyst files that i were created using Geostatistical wizard in ArcGIS 10. I want to save these files as Raster and use the 
File

Am i missing something, is there a way to do it faster ?

Comment: Please clarify the question.  Most of what the Geostatistical Analyst works on are raster files.  These are also most of the outputs.  There are other tables that are created by some of the functions as well.  If you were more specific about the functions that you ran and the outputs you created, it would help.

Comment: The Geostatistical wizard something called as GA files that are projected/created on the fly for SPEED, these can be then saved as raster files which i am trying to do

Answer (score 2):

The Geostatistical Wizard outputs geostatistical layers.  These are what you see displayed in ArcMap.  They are really just functions that take an (x,y) location and return a value.  A geostatistical layer doesn't "know" its own values until you ask it to calculate them.  The contours you see in ArcMap use a quick contouring algorithm; it calls the function the fewest number of times in order to draw roughly accurate contours.

When you use "GA Layer to Grid" to convert to a raster, the software has to call the function at the center of every raster cell.  That is why it often takes so long to convert: it has to call a geostatistical function at every single raster cell.  When your cell size is small, this can often be time consuming.

Comment: How do your prevent data from changing when you undertake "GA Layer to Grid" ?

Comment: *How do your prevent data from changing when you undertake "GA Layer to Grid" ?* The data doesn't "change". The contours may look different and have a different classification rendering, but this is due to the different locations where the geostatistical function is called. For a geostatistical layer, calculations are made purely to draw contours. When converting to raster, the function is called at the center of every raster cell, which requires many more calculations. See this blog for more information:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/09/29/understanding-geostatistical-analyst-layers/